# Auto increment row and column results to csv file in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, export-to-csv

I'm converting XML results to CSV using the following code. It will automatically increment the 'row' but I am having to set each 'column' value. I attempted to alter the code but the outcome was not functional. I believe the issue lies within the 'new XML' line but I haven't been able to find any information relating to this. So my question is can how can this be coded to auto increment the column value as well?'

Thank you - Matt

```
var length = msg['result'].length();
var x = 0;

for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
{

tmp['row'][x] = new XML("<row/>");
tmp['row'][x]['column1'] = '"'+msg['result'][i]['this'].toString()+'"';
tmp['row'][x]['column2'] = '"'+msg['result'][i]['that'].toString()+'"';
tmp['row'][x]['column3'] = '"'+msg['result'][i]['other'].toString()+'"';

x++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after some more testing and guesswork, I came up with the following that is fucntional and returns the output I am needing:

```
var length = msg['result'].length();
var x = 0;
// This is the number of columns I know will be returned
var z = 3;

for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
{

tmp['row'][x] = new XML("<row/>");
tmp['column'][z] = new XML("<column/>");

tmp['row'][x]['column'][z] = '"'+msg['result'][i]['this'].toString()+'"';
tmp['row'][x]['column'][z] = '"'+msg['result'][i]['that'].toString()+'"';
tmp['row'][x]['column'][z] = '"'+msg['result'][i]['other'].toString()+'"';

z++;
x++;
}
```